# Go to another view on button click - view is not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

"Test.cshtml" view is never found.

> ERROR: The view 'Test' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations.
>   The following locations were searched:

Among listed locations there are:

- `~/Views/SecondGroup/Test.aspx`
- `~/Views/SecondGroup/Test.ascx`
- `~/Views/SecondGroup/123.cshtml`

but not correct location which should be `"~/Views/SecondGroup/Test/123"` ??

ViewOne.cshtml (generated by FirstController)

```
<button onclick= "@("window.location.href ='" + @Url.Action("Test", 
"SecondController", new { id = "123" }) + "'");">
 GO TO ANOTHER VIEW
</button>
```

SecondController

```
public ActionResult Test(string id)
{           
    return View("Test", id);  // here id = '123'          
}
```

Test.cshtml

```
@model String
@{    
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div> .... </div>
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
---Controllers
     --- HomeController
     --- FirstController
     --- SecondController

-- Views
     --- FirstGroup
         --- ViewOne

     --- SecondGroup
         --- Test
```

---

Why `"Test.cshtml"` view is never found?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Test(string id)` method, you're using `return View("Test", id);` which uses [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.String%29) because the `type` of `id` is a `string`.

In that overload, the 2nd parameter is *the name of the master page or template to use when the view is rendered.*

You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.View%28System.String,System.Object%29) where the 2nd parameter is `object` (your model).

Change the code to cast the `string` to `object`:

```
public ActionResult Test(string id)
{           
    return View("Test", (object)id);       
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. For others who may have same issue: there are more ways to pass string model here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48796982/go-to-another-view-on-button-click-view-is-not-found